# Oracle SQL Regular expression to match Varchar column - treat as numbers

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table with a column whose data type is VARCHAR2(7 Char). The data in this column has values such as 1006,1007,2002 etc

I would like a regular expression that matches 4002,4003,4005,4011,4013 but NOT 4001.

First i tried using `To_number(columnName) > 4001` but got an ORA-01722 invalid number error.

I have then tried using `Regexp_like` unsuccessfully for this. I tried:

```
 1. 40[02,03,05,11,13]
 2. 40[0,1][^01]
 3. 40[0,1]([2,3,5,11])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

cheers

Comment: If you got ORA-01722 then at least some of the values in your column are not numbers (or, rather, strings that can be converted to numbers). Why isn't the column `number`? You should be using the correct data type. You've given some values that should and shouldn't natch but not a general rule. Your attempts suggest it has to start with 40, but what about 4020, or 4099, or any other number you haven't shown?

Comment: Why not just a simple `col in ('4002','4003','4005','4011','4013')`?

Comment: So the column is declared 7 characters, but the values are ALL four characters? Or are you looking for 4002 anywhere in a string that might be seven characters?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I only have read access to the database, so i cant modify table etc. You are right some of the data in that column contains a letter at the end and i guess thats why i get the oracle error. @trincot - im trying to eliminate the values i listed in a where clause which has other AND clauses so that wouldnt do in this situation. cheers

Comment: @mathguy - these entries that im looking to capture with regex are all 4 characters long and not contained in other strings

Comment: Then why do you want to do this with `regexp`?

Comment: *"im trying to eliminate the values i listed in a where clause which has other AND clauses..."*: please explain this in your question with a concrete example, because I can't see how that would make any difference between a `in ( )` and a `regexp_like` solution.

Comment: @Nick you need to read a regexp tutorial. Commas aren't used as separators inside `[]`.

Comment: @Barmar - yes i intend to. mathguy, i find regexp makes the sql statements shorter and more flexible as im not hardcoding specific values.Your thoughts?

Comment: It depends on how complicated the regexp is. But they often can't make use of an index, while a simple `IN (...)` can.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Im guessing queries that use an index are faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use this condition:

```
 col in ('4002','4003','4005','4011','4013')
```

If you really need to have to do it with `regexp_like`, then there are several ways to do it. Here are a few in order of decreasing readability and length:

```
 regexp_like(col, '^(4002|4003|4005|4011|4013)$')
 regexp_like(col, '^40(02|03|05|11|13)$')
 regexp_like(col, '^40(0[235]|1[13])$')
```

Do notice that classes in regular expressions (`[ ... ]`) list individual characters to match, not sequences.

Comment: Perhaps even `(4002|4003|4005|4011|4013)` for readability and ease of maintenance.

Comment: You should anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`. Otherwise it will match the numbers in the middle of other numbers.

Comment: @barmar - the OP confirmed the strings are four digits, despite the column being varchar2(7 char).

Comment: Very true, @Barmar, thanks for having highlighted that. Better be safe and not assume string lengths.

Comment: @mathguy, I tested that before commenting, and it works on my box. Of course with the anchors they become needed, so left those parentheses in now.

Comment: @mathguy Maybe I misinterpret, but I thought he meant that the numbers he's matching are all 4 digits, not all the column contents.

Comment: Thank you all and credit to @trincot ! This worked like a charm. I used the second regexp option above. need to learn this regex wizardry :)

Comment: @trincot - you are right, apologies - I missed the fact that showing the full number means that's the whole regexp, not part of it anymore. (It becomes part of it again with the anchors.)